# How to setup OpenNI2 and NITE with libfreenect2 for skeleton tracking on OSX?

Tags: macos, kinect, openni, kinect-v2, libfreenect2

I've just setup [libfreenect2](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2) on OSX 10.11.5 and I can successfully run the Protonect demo displaying RGB/IR/depth streams, but I'd like to use OpenNI/NITE for skeleton tracking as well.

I've followed the instructions in the repo's README file for OpenNI, but when I tried to run NiViewer I got this:

```
NiViewer 
openDevice failed:
    DeviceOpen using default: no devices found

Press any key to continue . . .
```

I'm currently going through libfreenect2 issues on github and documenting what I'm trying and the outcomes [here](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/issues/668). Any hints/tips are helpful.

<strike>What is the easiest way to setup and test OpenNI/NITE with libfreenect2 using a Kinect v2 on OSX ?</strike>

Turns out I was using NiTE 1.5 when I should've been using NiTE2.2
I simply copied `libfreenect2-openni2.0.dylib` from `libfreenect2/build/lib` to `NiTE-MacOSX-x64-2.2/Samples/Bin/OpenNI2/Drivers/` then ran the `SimpleUserTracker` sample and it worked !

There is still a catch: samples that just print to the console run, but the ones that open a window and render don't work. No window is rendered, as if that thread is blocked somehow.
That is when I use the integrated Intel GPU. If I use the discrete nVidia GPU the app crashes:

```
./UserViewer 
   124095 INFO       New log started on 2016-08-30 20:32:19
   124114 INFO       --- Filter Info --- Minimum Severity: VERBOSE
   126001 VERBOSE    No override device in configuration file
   126029 VERBOSE    Configuration has been read from '/Users/George/Downloads/Grouped/Projects/code+libs/NiTE-MacOSX-x64-2.2/Samples/Bin/OpenNI.ini'
   126034 VERBOSE    OpenNI 2.2.0 (Build 21)-MacOSX (May 29 2013 14:03:30)
   126038 VERBOSE    Using '/Users/George/Downloads/Grouped/Projects/code+libs/NiTE-MacOSX-x64-2.2/Samples/Bin/OpenNI2/Drivers' as driver path
   126042 VERBOSE    Looking for drivers in drivers repository '/Users/George/Downloads/Grouped/Projects/code+libs/NiTE-MacOSX-x64-2.2/Samples/Bin/OpenNI2/Drivers'
   161329 INFO       New log started on 2016-08-30 20:32:19
   161447 INFO       --- Filter Info --- Minimum Severity: VERBOSE
   161457 VERBOSE    Initializing USB...
   166761 INFO       USB is initialized.
   286714 INFO       New log started on 2016-08-30 20:32:19
   286762 INFO       --- Filter Info --- Minimum Severity: VERBOSE
   286781 VERBOSE    Initializing USB...
   286804 INFO       USB is initialized.
[Info] [Freenect2Impl] enumerating devices...
[Info] [Freenect2Impl] 7 usb devices connected
[Info] [Freenect2Impl] found valid Kinect v2 @20:16 with serial 500722542042
[Info] [Freenect2Impl] found 1 devices
  5380695 INFO       Found device freenect2://0
  5380723 INFO       Driver: register new uri: freenect2://0
  5381065 INFO       Device connected: Microsoft Kinect (freenect2://0)
  5381101 INFO       Device state changed: Microsoft Kinect (freenect2://0) to 0
  5381115 INFO       Driver: register new uri: freenect2://0?depth-size=640x480
  5381123 INFO       Device connected: Microsoft Kinect (freenect2://0?depth-size=640x480)
  5381132 INFO       Device state changed: Microsoft Kinect (freenect2://0?depth-size=640x480) to 0
  5381139 INFO       Driver: register new uri: freenect2://0?depth-size=512x424
  5381149 INFO       Device connected: Microsoft Kinect (freenect2://0?depth-size=512x424)
  5381157 INFO       Device state changed: Microsoft Kinect (freenect2://0?depth-size=512x424) to 0
[Info] [Freenect2Impl] enumerating devices...
[Info] [Freenect2Impl] 7 usb devices connected
[Info] [Freenect2Impl] found valid Kinect v2 @20:16 with serial 500722542042
[Info] [Freenect2Impl] found 1 devices
 10381916 VERBOSE    Trying to open device by URI '(NULL)'
 10381940 INFO       deiveOpen: freenect2://0
 10381948 INFO       Opening device freenect2://0
[Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] opening...
[Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] transfer pool sizes rgb: 20*16384 ir: 4*128*33792
[Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] opened
 12312037 VERBOSE    Initialize: Already initialized
 12314810 INFO       Device: createStream(depth)
 12314892 INFO       Freenect2Driver::Device: start()
[Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] starting...
[Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] submitting rgb transfers...
[Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] submitting depth transfers...
[Info] [Freenect2DeviceImpl] started
2016-08-30 20:32:31.847 UserViewer[7575:4995528] GLUT Warning: glutInit being called a second time.
[Info] [VTRgbPacketProcessor] avg. time: 19.633ms -> ~50.9346Hz
[Info] [VTRgbPacketProcessor] avg. time: 19.6306ms -> ~50.9408Hz
[Info] [VTRgbPacketProcessor] avg. time: 19.0744ms -> ~52.4262Hz
[Info] [DepthPacketStreamParser] 417 packets were lost
Segmentation fault: 11
```

How can I get past this issue ?

Comment: Are you sure your kinect is connected through usb 3 port??

Comment: Yes, of course, I can run the Protonect sample that comes with libfreenect2 and see the RGB/IR and depth streams

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference here are the above notes as an aswer.
This is what I did to get OpenNI2/NITE2.2 skeleton tracking with libfreenect2 and it's OpenNI2 driver. I have:

1. compiled installed OpenNI2 via homebrew and compiled libfreenect2 with OpenNI2 support as per [github repo's readme instructions](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/blob/master/README.md#mac-osx)
2. downloaded [NITE2.2](https://bitbucket.org/kaorun55/openni-2.2/src/2f54272802bf/NITE%202.2%20%CE%B1/?at=master) (replacing Nite1.5 which I was missusing before)
3. copied the libfreenect2 OpenNI2 driver (ibfreenect2/build/lib/libfreenect2-openni2.0.dylib) to the `Drivers` folder where I needed to run NITE2 (e.g. `NiTE-MacOSX-x64-2.2/Samples/Bin/OpenNI2/Drivers`).

I have figured out the path was wrong by setting the log level to verbose in OpenNI.ini:

```
[Log]
; 0 - Verbose; 1 - Info; 2 - Warning; 3 - Error. Default - None
Verbosity=0
LogToConsole=1
LogToFile=1

[Device]
;Override=""

[Drivers]
; Location of the drivers specified by a relative path based on OpenNI's shared library or an absolute path.
; Path separator "/" can be used to be portable for any platforms.
; Default - OpenNI2/Drivers
Repository=OpenNI2/Drivers
```

Symon Kaliski followed the notes and wrote a brilliant [Kinect 2 on OSX with skeleton tracking](http://szymonkaliski.com/blog/2017-01-18-kinect-2-osx/) post using [OpenFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc), be sure to check it out!

[image: OpenNI2 OpenFrameworks Skeleton tracking with Kinect v2]

Also, once libfreenect2 is compiled with openni2 support it can even be used in Processing, simply drop libfreenect2-openni2.0.dylib in `/Documents/Processing3/libraries/SimpleOpenNI/library/osx/OpenNI2` (on OSX):

[image: Kinect2 SimpleOpenNI Skeleton tracking]